# weird trig problem $\tan(\theta)=-\sqrt{2}\sin(\theta)$ on the interval $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

$\tan(\theta)=-\sqrt{2}\sin(\theta)$ on the interval $0 \leq \theta \lt 2\pi$

I  started off with  $[(\sin(\theta)/\cos(\theta)] \times (1/\sin(\theta) )= - \sqrt 2$,

then after simplification i got $(1/\cos(\theta))=-\sqrt 2$ and then i've got

$$\cos(\theta)= -(\sqrt{2}/2)$$

and   i got $\theta = 3\pi/4,5\pi/4$ but the right answer is  $\theta=0,\pi,3\pi/4,5\pi/4$.

I do not understand where did $0$ and $\pi$ came from? I mean at $0$ and $\pi$ $\theta$ is not equal to $-\sqrt{2}/2$ why is then $0$ and $\pi$ included?? I would appreciate if you could explain that.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want $\tan (\theta) = -\sqrt{2} \sin (\theta)$ in your title etc.?  Instead of $\tan (\theta) = -\sqrt{2 \sin (\theta)}$ ?  Cheers!

Comment: you are right, thanks for the correction

Comment: You're welcome; you might consider editing your post to reflect this correction.  Cheers!

Comment: It's OK; I did the edits. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

The other solutions come from solving $\sin\theta=0$. You can't just cancel the $\sin\theta$ just because it's a common factor, without considering the possibility it could be zero.

It's like when you solve the quadratic equation $x^2-3x=0$. Would you say that the only solution is $x=3$?

Comment: in which cases do we solve for sin(teta)=0? is it because the interval is (0 less or equal to teta LESS than 2pi)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "cases". In this question you have $\sin\theta=0$ and this gives you the two extra solutions for your interval, i.e. $0$ amd $\pi$

Comment: @john, when you multiply by $1/\sin\theta$, you introduce the possibility of additional solutions when $\sin\theta=0$.  Basically, you can't _just_ go from $ab=cb$ to conclude $a=c$; here $a=1/\cos\theta$ and $c=-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: This is an example of the well-known fallacy of "dividing by zero". It happens to be an especially expensive mistake if you are solving a trig equation, since you lose so many solutions.